# EF - 1:1 relation not on primary key

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I want to create an optional 1:1 mapping between two existing (legacy) tables where each `MainTable` record may or may not have - at most - one `SubTable` record:

```
internal class MainTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
internal class SubTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MainTableId { get; set; }
}
```

The `SubTable.Id` does not really serve any purpose but preferably it remains the PrimaryKey and AutoGenerated because of legacy code still running.

OnModelCreating gets updated with:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MainTable>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.Sub)
    .WithRequired(x => x.Main);
```

With the above Models, I run `Add-Migration initial` and `Update-Database`. I then update the models to:

```
internal class MainTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SubTable Sub { get; set; } // new
}
internal class SubTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MainTableId { get; set; }
    public MainTable Main { get; set; } // new
}
```

Running `Add-Migration` creates a new one but running it gives the following error: `Table 'dbo.SubTable' doesn't exist`

The generated migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropPrimaryKey("dbo.SubTable");
    AlterColumn("dbo.SubTable", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
    AddPrimaryKey("dbo.SubTable", "Id");
    CreateIndex("dbo.SubTable", "Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.SubTable", "Id", "dbo.MainTable", "Id");
}
```

I'm unsure why EF wants to drop all primary keys etc but the last line seems to suggest that it wants to bind Sub.Id->Main.Id while it should bind Sub.MainTableId->Main.Id.

After that I've tried messing with DataAnnotationAttributes instead `[ForeignKey]`, `[Index("name", 1, IsUnique = true)]` etc but to no avail.

Comment: I didn't find the real problem/solution but instead changed the database structure to avoid the problem altogether...

Answer (score 0):

Ill do something like this

```
internal class MainTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual SubTable Sub { get; set; } // new
}
internal class SubTable
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MainTableId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MainTableId")]
    public virtual MainTable Main { get; set; } // new
}
```

Comment: This gives me: `Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types` (without OnModelCreating). Or: `Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'MainTable_Sub_Target' in relationship 'MainTable_Sub'` (with OnModelCreating)